# Generic function to test response schema in Postman

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, postman

I have had a major headache in recent days creating test scripts to validate more than 300 endpoints of an application we are working on. In the end I came up with a very practical solution that boils down to: a generic JSON validation function and copying and pasting the expected result into an object for testing. This script perform each field validation for a maximum of 3 levels deep inside the JSON.

```
pm.globals.set("validationHelper", function validationHelper(example) {
    for (var field in example) {

        if (typeof example[field] === "object") {

            pm.test(`Field '${field}' is part of the response`, function () { 
                pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(field);
            });

            for (var nested in example[field]) {

                if (!Array.isArray(example[field][nested])) {

                    pm.test(`Nested field '${nested}' is part of the response`, function () {
                        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(nested);
                    });    

                } else {

                    pm.test(`Nested field '${nested}' is part of the response`, function () {
                        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(nested);
                    });

                    for (var index in example[field][nested]) {

                        if (typeof example[field][nested][index] === "object") {

                            if (!Array.isArray(example[field][nested][index])) {

                                for (var child in example[field][nested][index]) {

                                    pm.test(`Child field '${child}' is part of the response`, function () {
                                        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(child);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            pm.test(`Field '${field}' is part of the response`, function () { 
                pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(field);
            });

        }
    }
    return true
} + ';');
```

1. Using Postman, create a Pre-request Script in the collection that you will use to run the tests
2. Inside the request that you are going to test, paste the following code:

`// Save the example response used to validate
    // the body using a validation function
    example = {
        "detail": "Successfully logged out."
    }
    // This function loads the global helper function
    // and starts using the example schema
    eval(pm.globals.get("validationHelper"));
    validationHelper(example);`

3. The example object you have the save with the response that you are expecting.
4. Try to send the request and get all green

Postman documentation doesn't recommend to loop tests because of performance, but depending how much time you wanna save, this could be a good solution. :-)

Comment: This is great and thanks for sharing but it feels more like a short blog post than a question about something you need help with to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, I should have marked as a knowledge sharing not as a question. My fault!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found a more elegant solution for this same problem. ;-)

```
pm.globals.set("validationHelper", function validationHelper(example, keys = {}) {
  for (var k in example) {

    if (typeof example[k] == "object" && example[k] !== null) {
      if (k.constructor === String) {
        if (!k.match(/^-{0,1}\d+$/)) {
          existProperty = false
          for (var key in keys) {
            (key === k) && (existProperty = true)
          }
          if (!existProperty) {
            keys[k] = true
            pm.test(`Child field '${k}' is part of the response`, function () {
                pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(k);
            });
          }
        }
      }
      validationHelper(example[k], keys);

    } else {
      if (k.constructor === String) {
        if (!k.match(/^-{0,1}\d+$/)) {
          existProperty = false
          for (var key in keys) {
            (key === k) && (existProperty = true)
          }
          if (!existProperty) {
            keys[k] = true
            pm.test(`Child field '${k}' is part of the response`, function () {
                pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(k);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true
} + ';');
```